# How to manually make a line of words begin at a given position?

Tags: align

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\noindent
$\bullet$ Address: somewhere somewhere ...



\end{document}
```

Putting sufficiently many "somewhere", eventually the second line will start right below the given bullet. Denote the first character of the second line by C. Then how to manually put C to lie below a given character in the first line, say the first s preceded by the colon mark?

Comment: Use `\hangindent`.

Comment: Somehow it did not work. You meant I just have to type "\hangindent" at the beginning of the second sentence? @YiannisLazarides

Comment: Use `\hangindent` instead of `\noindent` (same position). Although this will not give you the degree of control you are asking for.

Comment: Appreciated. But how to precisely do that?

Comment: `\hangindent=5em ` will place the second line at 5em distance. Ideally you should measure the distance by putting `$\bullet$ Address: ` in box. I will post longer solution tonight if there are no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hangindent`. First measure what you need and then use it as shown below. Best to put everything in a macro, or to use one of the lists.

```
\bgroup
\parindent=0pt
\newsavebox\heading
\setbox\heading\hbox{HEADING}
\the\wd\heading

\hangindent\wd\heading 
HEADING long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas 


This is some long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas This is some long sequence of commnas
\egroup
```